# A count up timer doesn't setup error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer, count

A count up timer that won't  reset on refresh

```
var test;
var pageVisisted = new Date();
test = setInterval(function () {
var timeOnSite = new Date() - pageVisisted;

var secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000;
var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60) % 3600;
var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal) % 60;

document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = minutes + "." + seconds;


}, 1000);
```

I am spending lot of hours to setup the timer.But cannot able to done it.Anybody know how to solve these kind of Errors.
**For Example:** 
If I refresh these page at 1.26 seconds,countdown again started as 0.But it have to started at 1.26 after refresh.Can you solve that and tell me how to fix it.

Comment: what is the error - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EM8JD/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny  http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EM8JD/1/ If I refresh these page at 1.26 seconds,countdown again started as 0.But it have to started at 1.26 after refresh.Can you solve that and tell me how to fix it

Comment: @Steve so you want to persist this after refresh?

Comment: @JeffShaver Yes.Can You tell me?

Comment: @Steve that isn't default behavior. Things in JS don't really persist through a page refresh.. In order to persist them you likely have to use cookies or local/session storage.

Comment: May be helpful: [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store `pageVisited` value in `localStorage` (or better I guess in `sessionStorage`):

```
var pageVisited = +localStorage.pageVisited || +new Date();

var test = setInterval(function() {

    var timeOnSite = new Date() - pageVisited;

    var secondsTotal = timeOnSite / 1000;
    var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60) % 3600;
    var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal) % 60;

    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = minutes + "." + seconds;

}, 1000);

if (!localStorage.pageVisited) {
    localStorage.pageVisited = pageVisited;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HjxLX/

If you want the timer to be cleared after you close the browser window use `sessionStorage`.

IE support: IE8+.